# Python Temperature Converter issue with if statements

Tags: python

```
base_temperature = raw_input("Temperature to convert: ")
temp = int(base_temperature)
base_unit = raw_input("Current unit of measure (Please choose Celsius, Fahrenheit, or Kelvin): ")
base_unit = base_unit.lower()

if base_unit.lower() == "celsius" or "c":
    celsius = temp
    fahrenheit = celsius * 9/5 + 32
    kelvin = celsius + 273.15
    print "%s in Celsius  is %s in Fahrenheit and %s in Kelvin." % (celsius, fahrenheit, kelvin)

elif base_unit.lower() == "kelvin" or "k":
    kelvin = temp
    fahrenheit = kelvin * 9/5 - 459.67
    celsius = kelvin - 273.15
    print "%s in Kelvin is %s in Fahrenheit and %s in Celsius." % (kelvin, fahrenheit, celsius)

elif base_unit.lower() == "fahrenheit" or "f":
    fahrenheit = temp
    celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9
    kelvin = (fahrenheit + 459.67) * 5/9
    print "%s in Fahrenheit is %s in Celsius and %s in Kelvin." % (fahrenheit, celsius, kelvin)
```

Above is the code I have so far on a temperature converter, but my issue is that it appears to be 'ignoring' basically all the code besides taking in the base_temperature and then converting it from celsius to fahrenheit and kelvin. Even when I put in fahrenheit or kelvin for base_unit, it seems to ignore that and just work through the "if base_unit equals celsius" code regardless of the input into base_unit. So for example if I put in say 100 for base_temperature and "fahrenheit" for base_unit, it spits back out "100 in celsius is 212 in fahrenheit and 373.15 in kelvin. I'm extremely new to Python so I'm not entirely sure how to troubleshoot this, do I maybe need to create an actual function for converting from celsius, fahrenheit, or kelvin all separately?

Comment: In your own words, how is `base_unit.lower() == "celsius" or "c"` supposed to work? What are the conditions being combined with `or`?

Comment: There is no reason to use `elif` where a simple `if` will suffice. Also remember to put in something when all conditions fail.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that

```
base_unit.lower() == "celsius" or "c"
```

parses as

```
(base_unit.lower() == "celsius") or ("c")
```

`"c"` is implicitly convertible to boolean (it's `True`), so that condition is always true.  To fix it, try this instead:

```
base_unit.lower() == "celsius" or base_unit.lower() == "c":
```

Comment: You can also eliminate the .lower()'s in the if statement. There is a line just above all of the if clauses doing just that "base_unit = base_unit.lower()"

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this line and turn it to a more pythonic style:

```
base_unit.lower() == "celsius" or "c"
```

change it to:

```
if base_unit.lower() in ["celsius", "c"]:
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = float(input("the weather today is (temperature in Celsius) : "))
f = 9 * x / 5 + 32
print("%.1f C is %.1f F " % (x, f))

f = float(input("the weather today is (temperature in Fahrenheit ) :"))
x = (f - 32) * 5 / 9

print("%.1f F is %.1f C ." % (f, x))
```